# Helping changing FTPD default umask

Tags: redhat, ftp, init.d, umask

Default umask when logging in through FTP is 027 .

I want to change this to 002 so a process with the same group can consume an uploaded file.

Man 'ftpd' page says pass -u 002 to the ftpd command.  But my problem is I can't find where ftpd is started from.  So my question is, how to pass -u 002 to ftpd on startup?  I can't find an /etc/init.d/ script.

Details:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Linux  2.6.18-128.1.1.el5 )

RPM installed: ftp-0.17-35.el5  (rpm -qa  | grep ftp)

which ftpd: /usr/kerberos/sbin/ftpd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - your ftpd is not from ftp package. If you try `rpm -qf /usr/kerberos/sbin/ftpd` then you see a name of real one (something like krb5-appl-servers-1.0.1-7.el6_2.1.x86_64). This FTP server is started by xinetd and configuration is in /etc/xinetd.d/gssftp . One of parameters is:

```
server_args     = -l -a
```

and you can add your flags here:

```
server_args     = -l -a -u 002
```

next you must restart xinetd service (`service xinetd restart`) and it should work as you need.